# Two different answer while evaluating a limit

Tags: limits

> $$
> \lim_{x \to -1} \frac{\sqrt{\pi} - \sqrt{\cos^{-1} x}}{\sqrt{x+1}}
> $$

**Method 1**

So when i substitute $x=-1$ i get an indeterminant form $(0/0)$
 therefore i used LH rule in the beginning .[image]

Now when i substitute $x=-1$ i get my answer $0/ \pi\to 0$ as $0/$constant is not an indeterminant form

**Method 2** 
My book has solution different from me. My book first rationalised numerator and then used Lh rule. Thus the answer came out $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$

Can anybody point my or my book's mistake as i both answer can not  be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake when using L'Hôpital's rule. You should've gotten $\lim\limits_{x\to -1} \dfrac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\cos^{-1}x}\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}}=\lim\limits_{x\to -1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos^{-1}x}\sqrt{1-x}}.$ Now you can use direct substitution to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}},$ just like your textbook.